# Email google form via apps script automatically every day or week

Tags: forms, email

I have a form I would like to send out every day or every week in an email so it can be answered directly in Gmail.

In the form, I can only send it once through the interface. But I would like to send it automatically every day or once a week.

Can this be done through app scripts?

Cheers Mads

I thought there would be some setting for scheduling when to send a form out, but i have only seen 3rd party plugins for this that cost money.

I tried using this approach:
But that only gave me the look not the functioning form.

```
function sendForm(){
var form = FormApp.openByUrl(url);
var url = form.getPublishedUrl();
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var htmlBody = 
HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response).getContent();


MailApp.sendEmail({
to: 'name@gmail.com',
subject: 'Bek',
htmlBody: htmlBody,
});

}
```

Comment: Ok, apparently, this is a security issue. Sending forms automatically is not supported in a way that is directly embedded in emails and is not possible to do with scripts.  Cheers Mads